# R data.table doing an inner join on a field and operating on another?

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following scenario, I first create a data table as shown below

```
x = data.table(f1 = c('a','b','c','d'))
x = x[,rn := .I]
```

This yields

```
> x
   f1 rn
1:  a  1
2:  b  2
3:  c  3
4:  d  4
>
```

Where rn is simply the row number. Now, I have another data.table y as

```
y = data.table(f2=c('b','c','f'))
```

What I would like to be able to do is for elements in y that are in x, I want to subtract 2 from the corresponding values in rn. So the expected data.table is

```
x
   f1 rn
1: a  1
2: b  0
3: c  1
4: d  4
```

How does one get to this? `x[y]` and `y[x]` don't help at all as they just do joins.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `%chin%` in `i` to subset `x` by the required rows and then run your `j` expression...

```
x[ f1 %chin% y$f2 , rn := rn - 2L ]
x
#   f1 rn
#1:  a  1
#2:  b  0
#3:  c  1
#4:  d  4
```

`%chin%` is a fast version of the `%in%` operator specifically for character vectors that comes with `data.table`. Note that `2` should be `2L` to specify an `"integer"` type, otherwise you will get a warning (obviously don't use this if you are dealing with `"numeric"` data types).

Answer (score 5):

If your data is keyed, you can use a join like so:

```
setkey(x, f1)
x[y, rn := rn - 2L]
x
#   f1 rn
#1:  a  1
#2:  b  0
#3:  c  1
#4:  d  4
```